OpenAI GPT 4o with text+Image input and Image output possible?
I can do this in chatgpt.com chat.

But I can't do it via API.
So I want to do text+image input and get image output. The output image should be the modified version of input image according to the given prompt.
I checked OpenAI API documentation, but they only provide

text to image
image inpaint (with mask mandatory)
image variation (without text prompt)

Anyone can help on this, please?
